# What is the bottleneck with standard streams displayed in terminals?

Tags: terminal, stdout

If a program writes to a console or terminal, in my experience it tends to run slow, much slower than if the output is redirected, or if it uses other output methods to begin with, not `stderr` or `stdout`. I'm sure I'm experiencing this in Windows, but if I remember well, maybe Linux has this too.

What is the bottleneck in either hardware, OS, protocol, or otherwise, that is the cause of this effect?

Comment: As @faffaffaff says, it's doing a tremendous amount of window-painting.

Answer (score 4):

When displaying on the terminal, your terminal needs to parse the stream for terminal control codes (ANSI,VT-100, etc), maintain terminal state (cursor positions, etc etc), and then render a bitmap representation (which can consist of thousands or millions of pixel bytes) several frames per second. This is much slower than simply dumping the bytes to a disk file.